# Why is my defined variable undefined

Tags: php, scope

I declared a new variable `$var` at the top of my document. Afterwards, I called a function which should output this variable.
Unfortunately, I get the following message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: var

This is my code:

```
$var = "abc";

func ();
function func() {
    echo $var;
}
```

Comment: you should pass the $var variable to the function, for example func($var)

Comment: Review [PHP's documentation on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It is different from other languages (like JavaScript for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, functions cannot access variables that are within the global scope unless the keyword `global` is used to 'import' the variable into the function's scope.

You would fix it by doing this:

```
function func() {
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
```

Read more about scoping here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.
>
> In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

Global variables can also be accessed using `$GLOBALS` although I would avoid using that unless absolutely necessary.

> A second way to access variables from the global scope is to use the special PHP-defined $GLOBALS array.

Worth mentioning:

It's worth linking to this discussion on globals and why you may not want to use them: [Globals are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/747678)
. I'd say there is a preference to use classes instead, or simply pass in the variable as an argument to the function.  I won't say not to use globals but at the very least be mindful of its use.

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice post!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the scope of the variable, either you define it as global, or you pass it as a parameter.

Check the comments under this post:
[Variables Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/1052155)

Answer (score 0):

The scoping of your variable is wrong. You will need to either pass it as a function parameter or declare it as Global in the function. Please review [function scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You could do something like this:

```
$var = "abc";

func ();
function func() {
    global var;
    echo $var;
}
```